# Cómo obtener el responseText con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

tengo el siguiente código en JavaScript para obtener el total de ventas:

```
function total_ventas_vs(the_value) { 
  var the_user = the_value; 
  var answer; 

  var the_quantity = $.ajax({
    url: "../controlador/dashboard/controlador_cantidadventas_vs.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      idusu: the_user
    }
  }).done(resp => {

    answer = JSON.parse(resp); 
    return answer; 

  }); 

  console.log(typeof the_quantity);
  // console.log(parseInt(the_quantity.responseText.value)); 
  return the_quantity; 
}
```

Y el de acá en donde imprimo el resultado del retorno de la función `total_ventas_vs(the_value)`:

```
function F1() {

        var suma; 

        Array.from(document.querySelector("#cbm_supervisor").options).forEach(function(option) {
            let value = parseInt(option.value); 
            let result; 
            
            result = total_ventas_vs(value); 
            console.log(result); 
            

        })     

}
```

Lo que me retorna en consola es lo siguiente:

[image: Consola]

Lo que requiero es obtener el valor de la propiedad `responseText`:

[image: El responseText]

He intentando acceder al parámetro de distintas formas, pero sólo me retorna **undefined o el objeto entero**.

Comment: Las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas, por tanto, no es correcto hacer un `return answer; ` puedes: 1. Usar `answer` en ese mismo contexto; 2. Crear una función que reciba a `answer` en parámetro y llamarla desde el done con algo como `laFuncion(answer);` 3. Implementar un callback.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu respuesta compañero, lo acabo de modificar... te referías a la opción 2 como algo así ? [Código modificado](https://pastebin.com/h8QLuW5C)

Comment: Más o menos, sólo que en `the_real_function` ya usas a `answer`, no tienes que retornarla a ninguna parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví el problema modificando la petición AJAX para que **no sea** asíncrona, de tal forma que la función queda así:

```
function total_ventas_vs(the_value) { 
  var the_user = the_value; 
  var answer; 

  $.ajax({
    url: "../controlador/dashboard/controlador_cantidadventas_vs.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      idusu: the_user
    }, 
    async: false,
    success: function(text) {
        answer = text; 
    }
  })

  return parseInt(answer); 
  
}
```

- Se realiza la petición AJAX con JQuery y se establece el parámetro `async` como `false`
- De tal forma, establecer la variable `answer` (anteriormente declarada) en el `success` para que tome el texto del `responseText`
- En mi caso requería el valor en entero por tanto (y finalmente) lo que hice fue retornar el valor en entero con `parseInt`

Gracias a [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) por su ayuda.